# Error when trying to answer a call using Twilio Client: "Missing audio element in offer"

Tags: twilio

Here's the console output when I set up Twilio.Device in debug mode:

```
[Device] Stream is ready
twilio.js:2115 [Connection] Received HANGUP from gateway
twilio.js:2115 [Connection] Received an error from the gateway:
twilio.js:2115 Object {code: 31100, message: "Missing audio element in offer", connection: Connection}
twilio.js:2115 [Device] 31100: Missing audio element in offer
twilio.js:1103 Uncaught Twilio.Exception: 31100: Missing audio element in offer
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This appears to be a bug in Chrome Canary, version 40.0.2179.0.  My workaround is to use regular Chrome (version 37.0.2062.124).

Comment: FYI, I receive this same error in Chrome for Mac v39.0.2171.13 beta (64-bit)